# I am trying to create a new column that is conditional upon the contents of existing columns

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, na

I am trying to make several new columns in my data frame that are conditional upon the contents of a few existing columns.

In pseudo-code, the arguments basically go "If VariableA is 1 and either VariableB is 2 or VariableC is 3, then make VariableD = 1, and if it does not meet these conditions make it a zero.

I have tried using for loops and ifelse statements, but have had no luck. I know that the logic of my commands are correct, but I am making some error translating it into R syntax, which isn't surprising because I just started using R about a week ago.

Below is a simplified version of what I have tried doing...

Data$VariableD <- ifelse(Data$VariableA == 'Jim' && (Data$VariableB == 2 || Data$VariableC == 3), 1, 0)

It runs without error, but upon examining the contents of VariableD, all cells are filled with "NA"

Here is an example using a similar dataset, notice row 1 meets the criteria. (I can't make a proper table to save my life, but I think it's interpretable.

### |Variable A|Variable B|Variable C|Variable D|

### |1|    Jim   |     2    |     4    |    NA    |

### |2|    Tom   |     2    |     3    |    NA    |

|3|    Tom   |     3    |     4    |    NA    |

Comment: It seems to me the code has no problem. Can you please post an example dataset showing the issue? You can use ````dput```` to show the data to us.

Comment: Your code is logically correct. You need to check the difference between `&` and `&&` operator in R.

Comment: It's not causing you your issue, but you've got `VariableA == 3` instead of `VariableC == 3`

Comment: I updated the question to include an example dataset and change the code example a bit to more accurately reflect what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the class of your variables? Could be a problem of class...(by example you put `==1` for variableA, but if variableA is a class chr should be `== "1"`).

Could you please also provide your full loop?

Otherwise, please try that:

```
Data$VariableD <- ifelse(Data$VariableA == 1 & (Data$VariableB == 2 | Data$VariableA == 3), 1, 0)
```